# How do apps such as Fing detect machines on network?

Tags: networking

Unlike some other IP scanners, the Fing android app can detect the Windows 10 machines on my network (and provide IP and MAC address) despite the fact that the latest default Windows firewall settings mean that there are no open ports and the machines do not respond to pings. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some info about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099108/how-does-ios-app-fing-get-mac-address

Basically it sends ARP requests through your network and builds a MAC/IP table based on that.